# How can I measure CPU time of a specific set of threads?

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, performance, measure

I run C++ program in Linux.

There are several threads pool (for computation, for io, for ... such things).

The system call clock() gives me a way to measure the CPU time spent by all the CPU cores for the process.

However, I want to measure the CPU time spent only by the threads in the computation threads pool.

How can I achieve it?

Thanks :D

Comment: This is not ideal, but i think the easiest solution is to log some message with timestamps of start and stop of each thread and get you timings by postprocessing those logs.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To get `CPU clock ID` of every thread you can use: [pthread_getcpuclockid](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_getcpuclockid.3.html)
and using this `CPU clock ID` you can retrieve the current thread CPU time using: [clock_gettime](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clock_gettime.2.html).

Following is the sample code to demonstrate the same:

```
struct timespec currTime;
clockid_t threadClockId;

//! Get thread clock Id
pthread_getcpuclockid(pthread_self(), &threadClockId);
//! Using thread clock Id get the clock time
clock_gettime(threadClockId, &currTime);
```

Comment: It seems you can also call `clock_gettime(CLOCK_THREAD_CPUTIME_ID, &currTime)` according to [manual](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clock_gettime.2.html) so you don't need pthread dependency.