# Implementing a profiler for worker thread tasks

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads, profiler

I have a number of worker threads which work on tasks called `class Task`. I'm using C++ on x86_64 Windows/Mac/Linux. While working on each task, I can update a global `Task* activeTasks[]` array so that the application knows when each worker is processing which task.

```cpp
activeTasks[threadId] = &task;
task.work();
activeTasks[threadId] = NULL;
```

I would like to write a simple *in-application* profiler so that the user can see how many microseconds have been spent on each task.

An additional complication is that tasks may call `sleep()` inside their `work()` function. The profiler should only sample a task when the thread is active, not sleeping or suspended by the scheduler.

How could a profiler like this be implemented?
It seems this is exactly how profilers like `perf` work, except they inspect the current call stack rather than an `activeTasks` array.

#### Attempts

A naive idea is to launch a separate profiler thread that periodically checks `activeTasks[threadId]` every few microseconds, incrementing a counter for each task if the worker thread is in a running state. This can be checked with `thread.ExecutionState == 3` on Windows and possibly some way with pthreads.
But the issue is that on single-core machines, running a profiler thread and any of the worker threads is never simultaneous, so the profiler would always see the worker as "suspended".

Another idea is to trigger some sort of interrupt, but I have no idea how this is done.

Comment: You cannot profile something outside your control, i.e. the scheduler. You have to rewrite the Sleep() function to trigger off your profiler, then on timeout trigger it on again. Interrupts cannot be triggered in a user level application.

Comment: Outside of what @MichaelChourdakis pointed out, you cand simply wrap your worker functions in a _timer_ function as I explain [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22387757/1673776). Also, you can update your `activeTasks` via a mutex so you prevent race conditions.

Comment: I hope you are protecting any access (read or write) to `activeTasks` with a mutex or other synchronization primitive. Otherwise you have a data race and are deep into undefined behaviour land (and you *do not* want to be there).

Comment: @Victor  Of course, but I didn't think the thread-safety of my pseudocode was relevant to this question.

Comment: @Victor But would that timer function incorrect count time spent sleep()ing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want to measure thread CPU time.

There are ways to do that in Win32 (using [GetThreadTimes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-getthreadtimes)) and pthreads (using [pthread_getcpuclockid](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44917411/485343)).

```
long startTime = getThreadCPUTime();
task.work();
long endTime = getThreadCPUTime();
// lock mutex
taskTimes[taskType] += endTime - startTime;
// unlock mutex
```

Comment: Thanks, your references to the two "thread CPU time" functions are the key. I didn't know this existed for both platforms, and it solves the issue of inactive threads without periodic sample profiling.

Answer (score 1):

The simple implementation is to have a class that can be toggled on/off, then at the end of the (say) function log a counter. Having another thread doing that is bad because you would consume CPU time on polling time, which is bad.

```
class PROFILE
{
 private: unsigned long long start = 0,consumedtime = 0;
 public:
    PROFILE()
    {
     on();
    }
    ~PROFILE()
    {
     off();
     log(consumedtime); // e.g. save to a global array with a mutex
    }

    void on()
    {
     start = some_tick(); // E.g. GetTickCount64() on Windows
    }
    void off()
    {
     auto end = some_tick();
     consumedtime += end - start;
    }

   void sleep(int ms)
   {
    off();
    Sleep(ms); // Win
    on();
   }
}

void foo()
{
    PROFILE pr;
    ...
    pr.sleep(500);
    ...
}
```

Comment: Is the difference between `some_tick()` and `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now()` that the former is thread-time and while latter is in real-time? In other words, if `work()` has `sleep()`, will the former not count the time sleeping?

Comment: some_tick() is any function that can give you a current tick, I edited to provide an off/on function. If you sleep during a function, you must trigger the profiler off manually.

Comment: Thanks, if combining this implementation with @rustyx's answer, I believe is a sufficient alternative to sample profiling.